# How to get my serializer to handle more than one rec and not return 'None' for field values that have data in them

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My model serializer is currently returning 'None' in every field for the two records being retrieved, although there is data in those fields on the table. I'm having trouble determining how to call it correctly.

Here is the model:

```
class Form(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    header = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    submit_button_label = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

Here is my serializer definition:

```
class FormSerializer(DefaultSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = page_builder_models.Form
```

Here is code that works, but doesn't *seem* like the best way of doing things:

```
pf_qs = p.form.all().values()

form_list = []
for i in pf_qs:
    temp_dict = dict()
    temp_dict = page_builder_serializers.FormSerializer(page_builder_models.Form.objects.get(pk=i['form_id'])).data
    form_list.append(temp_dict)

print(form_list)
```

And this is the data that print statement is returning:

```
[{u'id': 1, 'name': u'test_form', 'header': u'Test Form Header', 
'body': u'This is just some test text for the Form Body field', 
'submit_button_label': u'Submit it!', 
'edited': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 22, 7, 50, 22), 
'created': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 22, 7, 50, 24)}, 

{u'id': 2, 'name': u'another_test_form', 'header': u'Second Test Form', 
'body': u'blah blah blah', 'submit_button_label': u'Faggetaboutit', 
'edited': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 24, 4, 35, 20), 
'created': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 24, 4, 35, 24)}]
```

This is the code that I'm *attempting* to get working:

```
try:  # a Page can have multiple Form recs
    forms = page_builder_serializers.FormSerializer(pf_qs, many=True).data
except page_builder_models.Form.DoesNotExist:
    return rest_response.Response(data={'error': "form record cannot be found"}, status=404)
```

And this is what gets printed in the terminal from that:

```
[{u'id': 1, 'name': None, 'header': None, 'body': None, 
'submit_button_label': None, 'edited': None, 'created': None}, 

{u'id': 2, 'name': None, 'header': None, 'body': None, 
'submit_button_label': None, 'edited': None, 'created': None}]
```

Any and all help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `is_valid()` before the `.data` attribute will have values.

Otherwise the values are indeed `None`.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I am a bit confused still though...isn't `is_valid()` only used for save? I'm only attempting to read in this block of code.

Comment: The data needs to be validated before you can safely use it (either to save or for other purposes).

Comment: When I `print(forms.is_valid())`, I get "False".

Comment: In that case there's a problem with the data, according to the serialiser. Are the objects valid?